# How to combine multiple crosstab queries into one with sequential columns, i.e. profile to landscape format?

Tags: ms-access, crosstab

I have a water quality dataset in MS Access currently in a profile/condensed format. I need to re-format into a landscape/spreadsheet format.  I have 5 crosstab queries built into MS Access that correctly split out analyte, units, qualifiers, MRL, MDL as a landscape.  I want to combine the 5 crosstab queries such that the columns are ordered analyte->units->qualfiers->MRL->MDL in a spreadsheet format.  Any help is appreciated.

A union query isn't working for what I need... that I can tell.  A union query adds data from each crosstab as appended rows, not columns.  Close... but not quite.

Code from 1 of the 5 Crosstabs:

```
TRANSFORM First([MRP Data].[Result Value]) AS [FirstOfResult Value]
SELECT [MRP Data].[Lab Sample ID], [MRP Data].Collection, [MRP Data].[Lab ID], [MRP Data].[Lab Receipt Date]
FROM [MRP Data]
GROUP BY [MRP Data].[Lab Sample ID], [MRP Data].Collection, [MRP Data].[Lab ID], [MRP Data].[Lab Receipt Date]
ORDER BY [MRP Data].Collection
PIVOT [MRP Data]![Analyte] & ", " & [MRP Data]![Sample Fraction] & " " & "(" & [MRP Data]![Units] & ")";
```

The end point of this should be a spreadsheet/landscape format that I can use for data analysis.

Comment: So what is the common unique identifier field in each CROSSTAB - [Lab Sample ID]? You have a table for these unique identifiers? Join the CROSSTABs to that table.

Comment: Hi...yes [Lab Sample ID] is unique.  Right now I don't have a stand-alone table of sample ID's, but will make one and try the joined CROSSTABS.

Comment: Actually, if the CROSSTABs will all have same [Lab Sample ID] values, one of them can serve as 'parent' and others join to it.